# MethodNotAllowedHttpException using Href

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, routes

I'm trying to verify if an api we use in work is working

with Href, using the route /test/intent/ it should execute the controller and check if its working or not

blade.php

```
@section('content')
 <div class="container">
 <div class="col-12 mt-5 text-center">
    <a href="/test/intent" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Test</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 @endsection
```

route:

```
Route::post('/test/intent', 'Testing\DebitTestController@intent');
```

the error we are getting is

MethodNotAllowedHttpException

```
    /**
 * Throw a method not allowed HTTP exception.
 *
 * @param  array  $others
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 */
protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}

/**
 * Get routes from the collection by method.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $method
 * @return array
 */
public function get($method = null)
{
    return is_null($method) ? $this->getRoutes() : Arr::get($this->routes, $method, []);
}

/**

enter code here
```

Comment: few details found in the question but anyway: `href` is typically found on `a` tags which will make a `GET` request to the link found in the `href` attribute and as your route expects a `POST` request you get a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` which is the desired and the expected behavior.

Comment: `<a href="{{ route('/cardetails', ['121','cars'] ) }}">click </a>` In URL it will be like this below line.

`127.0.0.1:8000/cardetails/121/cars`

Comment: I switch to GET and still get the same error, also the href now is <a href="{{url('test/intent')}}"

I'm using laravel 5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use `url()` helper if you don't want to name the route for some reason:

```
<a href="{{ url('admin/views/query/new_query') }}"
```

Comment: I still get the same error even doing this. I'm using laravel 5.5

Comment: Do you need to send GET or POST?